# Expedited review - send again or not? ios application

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I have submitted an app for expedited review. Immediately after that I have rejected the binary and published a new one.

Do I have to resubmit my app for expedited review or will Apple consider my first submission? Or if I resubmit it again, will it be considered as spam?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the first one is enough.
However It's Apple, so nobody really knows.

Information from [App Review](https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/app-review/) Support center

> Expedited App Review
>
> If you face extenuating circumstances, you can request the review of your app to be expedited. These circumstances include fixing a critical bug in their your app on the App Store or releasing their your app to coincide with a an event they you are directly associated with,
>
> Urgent Bug Fix
>
> If you've submitted an update to fix a critical bug in your app on the App Store and you are requesting an expedited review, be sure to include the steps to reproduce the bug on the current version of your app.
>
> Time-Sensitive Event
>
> For apps associated with an event, we recommend you plan and schedule the release of your app in iTunes Connect. However, if your app is stil in review and the launch of your event is quickly approaching, you can request to have your app review expedited. When submitting your request, it's important to include the event, date of the event, and your app's association with the event.
>
> Please Note: Expedited reviews are granted on a limited basis and we cannot guarantee that every request will be expedited. Sign in to request an expedited review.

Comment: Does "app stuck in waiting for review queue for over 3 days indicating there's a bug in Apple's system" qualify as a legitimate reason to request expedited app review? I don't see any other way of breaking out of the infinite waiting.