# App Store Expedited Review has been accepted and i rejected/resubmitted binary

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

I applied for expedited review and it has been approved. My app status was  "Waiting for review". While editing my meta data i accidentally removed the binary but immediately resubmitted it again. Now, do i have to apply for expedited review again or the previous one is still available?

**edit:**

When submitting an expedited review you receive this message: "We'll evaluate your request and get back to you shortly. Please note that if you reject your binary in iTunes Connect, your app cannot be reviewed and this request will be canceled."

I send another expedited review explaining them that i rejected and resubmited binary again after receiving expedited review acceptance via e-mail and ask them if it is still available. This is what i received:

"Thank you for contacting App Store Review to request an expedited review. After evaluating your request, we have determined it is a duplicate to one or more previous requests for , that you or another team member have recently submitted.

If your previous request was accepted, and your app is rejected during the expedited review cycle, it is not necessary to request another Expedited Review when you resubmit. Once you revise and resubmit your binary (or metadata, in the case of a Metadata Rejection), your app will be automatically returned to the expedite queue."

Now, i am still confused by "app rejected during the expedited review cycle" they mean if it is rejected by app reviewer or developer reject also counted?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to reapply. Once approved, they take whichever binary is waiting when they get to it. Your app is already in the short queue (which I believe is still about a day or two wait right now, better than the normal queue that's about 12-14 days right now).

Comment: 7 hours passed but the status is still "Waiting for review". Are you sure that it is in expedited queue? Again, i rejected binary after i receive an e-mail that says my expedited review been approved.

Comment: Should be yes. I don't work for them, so I can't see of course, but from experience you should be fine. And 7 hours is still short for an expedited review right now. I had to expedite a review a couple of weeks ago, and it was still 2 days wait, but that's still a lot faster than the normal queue.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! You made me feel better now. I don`t know what is going on but these days it took really long for app approval in regular way.

Comment: Did you actually reject your binary and resubmit it in your experience? I mean after you got expedited review approved.

Comment: I did not, but I recall it specifically calling out that if you do reject the binary, that you don't need to reapply. See also this older question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704920/expedited-review-send-again-or-not-ios-application

Comment: The answer of Aaron made me confused. So, i am not sure if rejecting before or after make any difference in this situation. Anyway i better sit and wait a bit more to be sure.

Comment: @Amidos I agree with Dave's answer. I've rejected and resubmitted my binary after receiving an expedited review and Apple still proceeded with the expedited review.

Comment: Lyndsey nice! That makes a point. So basically you did it while your app was in "waiting for review" status? How long did it take for you to get "in review" status in this case?

Comment: @DaveWood and Lyndsey i have edited my question. May be this will give you more information.

Comment: Just for information. I received answer from app review team that developer rejection does not cancel expedited review. But, my app haven`t been reviewed yet for some reason. It is still in "waiting for review" status. May be it is because of the volume of submissions.

Comment: I've done the same thing. Still waiting for review :(